# How to tranfer a call in switchvox to particular operator via the API

Tags: java, switchvox

How to transfer a call in switchvox to particular operator via the API?

I need to call transfer/assign to a operator any API is there for this purpose.

Comment: too specific a question... read the manual.

Comment: The API doesn't support it at the moment. http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=73154&p=153913&hilit=transfer&sid=6096b11b90af9a74acec2ed0f50e6766#p153913

Comment: is possible internal tranfer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you're responding to an event. Other than that there is no way to grab a call in progress and transfer it.